# Likelihood of drawing at least the expectation of a collection of IID variables

Tags: probability

I have a collection of $N$ IID random variables, each distributed as { $\frac{1}{2}$:1, $\frac{1}{3}$:0, $\frac{1}{6}$:-1}. The expectation of this distribution is $\frac{1}{3}$, and unlesss I'm mistaken the expectation of the sum of the collection should be $\frac{N}{3}$.

I want to find the probability that if I draw from each variable in the collection and sum the results, the total will be at least some target number. I wrote code for this that appears to be working (checked by hand for $N$ = 1 and 2, verified expectation of sum distribution for $N$ up to 30).

However, according to the results, it appears that the probability of achieving at least the expectation of the sum decreases with $N$:

```
collection size | expectation | ~probability of achieving expectation
3               | 1           | 66.67
6               | 2           | 62.15
9               | 3           | 60.05
12              | 4           | 58.76
```

My naive intuition is that the probability of drawing at least the expectation of the sum should not vary with the size of the collection. Is there likely a bug in my code, or is there something else at work here?

Comment: This might be because $P(S_N=E(S_N))$ decreases when $N$ grows and because you are evaluating $P(S_N\ge E(S_N))$. My guess is that $P(S_N>E(S_N))$ increases.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. So for much larger values of $N$ it would converge?

Comment: See @joriki's answer for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naive intuition is wrong. The probability of achieving at least the expectation can be very far from $\frac12$; for instance, if you pick a person uniformly at random, chances are very high that she will have an above-average number of arms. But if you have N independent identically distributed variables, according to the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) the distribution of their average tends to a normal distribution, so the probability that at least the expectation is achieved tends to $\frac12$ (and hence varies with $N$).